# How do I remove single quotes from a table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I searched around quite a bit, it would be great if someone could link me to a solution or answer my query.
The thing is I have a postgresql table that contains a lot of single quotes and I cant figure out how to get rid of them, because obviously this

```
  update tablename set fieldname= NULL where fieldname=' ;
```

wont work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Better use [**replace()**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) for this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = replace(col, '''', '');
```

Much faster than [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.23.1.1.1), and it replaces "globally": all occurrences of the search string. To achieve the same with `regexp_replace()`, add an optional 4th parameter:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = regexp_replace(col, '''', '', 'g');
```

`'g'` for "globally".

Aside: the canonical (and SQL standard) way to **escape single quotes** (`'`) in string literals is to double them (`''`). Using Posix style escape sequences works, too, of course. See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Comment: How about replacing double quotes with single quotes?

Comment: @Timothy: `replace(col, '"', '''')`

Answer (score 2):

```
update tablename set fieldname= NULL where fieldname='''' ;
```

or

```
update tablename set fieldname= NULL where fieldname=E'\'' ;
```

Comment: Both of them didn't work, dont know if Im missing something here.

Comment: Maybe there are spaces in the values. Try `SELECT '*' || fieldname || '*' FROM tablename` to check it.

Answer (score 0):

`insert into table1(data) values ($$it's a string, it's got some single quotes$$)`

Use $$ before and after the string. It will insert data.