# PostgreSQL group by season (northern and southern hemisphere)

Tags: postgresql, date, postgis, between

I have data points distributed over the whole globe. Every data point has a timestamp.

I want to group the data by the seasons, as shown in this picture (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season#/media/File:Seasons1.svg).

[image]

This is what I tried so far (winter 2011/2012 in the northern hemisphere):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
    WHERE my_date BETWEEN '2011-12-21' AND '2012-03-21'
    AND ST_Y(ST_Centroid(geom)) > 0;
```

How can I do this for all possible years? I tried ...OR date BETWEEN... but this is very slow.

How is it possible to select both winter in the northern and southern hemisphere?

**Update**

For all winter data on the northern hemisphere I use this query:

```
CREATE TABLE season_winter_north AS WITH first_step AS (
SELECT
    id,
    extract(month from my_date)::int AS month,
    extract(day from my_date)::int AS day,
    ST_Centroid(geom) AS geom
FROM mytable 
    WHERE ST_Y(ST_Centroid(geom)) > 0)

(SELECT * FROM first_step
    WHERE month = 12
        AND day >= 21)

UNION ALL

(SELECT * FROM first_step
    WHERE month = ANY('{1,2}'))

UNION ALL

(SELECT * FROM first_step
    WHERE month = 3
        AND day<21)
```

Is there a more elegant or efficient solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t(my_date) as (
    values ('2012-07-01'::date), ('2013-03-30'), ('2013-10-12'), ('2013-01-10')
)
select 
    case 
        when my_date between 
            make_date(extract(year from my_date)::int, 3, 21)
            and
            make_date(extract(year from my_date)::int, 6, 20)
        then 'spring'
        when my_date between 
            make_date(extract(year from my_date)::int, 6, 21)
            and
            make_date(extract(year from my_date)::int, 9, 22)
        then 'summer'
        when my_date between 
            make_date(extract(year from my_date)::int, 9, 23)
            and
            make_date(extract(year from my_date)::int, 12, 20)
        then 'fall'
        else 'winter'
    end as season,
    my_date
from t
;
season |  my_date   
--------+------------
summer | 2012-07-01
spring | 2013-03-30
fall   | 2013-10-12
winter | 2013-01-10
```

Comment: I'm using postgresql 9.3.9. There is no function called make_date.

Answer (score 1):

More succinctly, and probably with better performance:

```
with t(my_date) as (
values ('2012-07-01'::date), ('2013-03-30'), ('2013-10-12'), ('2013-01-10') )
    select 
    case 
        when to_char(my_date,'MMDD') between '0321' and '0620' then 'spring'
        when to_char(my_date,'MMDD') between '0621' and '0922' then 'summer'
        when to_char(my_date,'MMDD') between '0923' and '1220' then 'fall'
        else                                                        'winter'
    end as season,
    my_date
    from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to post this additional answer to my question. With this query there is no need to use the function make_date (only available with postgresql 9.4.).

With the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15318003) your able to create a make_date() function for other versions of PostgreSQL.

I have created the function as well and I recognized a significant difference in speed. But I don't know, if the make_date() function in 9.4. is faster.

```
select 
case 
    when my_date between 
        (extract(year from my_date)::int||'-03-21')::date
        and
        (extract(year from my_date)::int||'-06-20')::date
    then 'spring'
    when my_date) between 
        (extract(year from my_date)::int||'-06-21')::date
        and
        (extract(year from my_date)::int||'-09-22')::date
    then 'summer'
    when my_date) between 
        (extract(year from my_date)::int||'-09-23')::date
        and
        (extract(year from my_date)::int||'-12-20')::date
    then 'fall'
    else 'winter'
end as season,
my_date
from my_table;
```

The query without make_date() is about 3 to 4 times faster then with make_date.