# How to select a single quoted column using postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
Select COLUMN_name  
from TABLE_name 
where COLUMN NAME = 'something's'
```

While executing this query in PostgreSQL, it is showing an error as like below,
syntax error at or near "S".

Comment: If you study this in your SQL editor, does anything pop-out at you? Even just studying this with your eyes, does the embedded **single quote** mean anything of importance?

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe in `KEPLER'S` is terminating the string early. [Escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12316953/139010), and proofread next time.

```
Select CONCEPTNAME from KM_CONCEPT_MAST where CONCEPTNAME='KEPLER''S LAWS OF PLANETARY MOTION'
```