# Writing an SQL trigger to find if number appears in column more than X times?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I want to write a Postgres SQL trigger that will basically find if a number appears in a column 5 or more times. If it appears a 5th time, I want to throw an exception. Here is how the table looks:

```
create table tab(
first integer not null constraint pk_part_id primary key,
second integer constraint fk_super_part_id references bom,
price integer);

insert into tab values(1,NULL,100), (2,1,50), (3,1,30), (4,2,20), (5,2,10), (6,3,20);
```

Above are the original inserts into the table. My trigger will occur upon inserting more values into the table.

Basically if a number appears in the 'second' column more than 4 times after inserting into the table, I want to raise an exception. Here is my attempt at writing the trigger:

```
create function check() return trigger as '
begin
    if(select first, second, price
          from tab
          where second in (
            select second from tab
            group by second
            having count(second) > 4)
) then
raise exception ''Error, there are more than 5 parts.'';
end if;
return null;
end 
'language plpgsql;

create trigger check
after insert or update on tab
for each row execute procedure check();
```

Could anyone help me out? If so that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This sounds like business logic that should be handled on the front end, outside of the database.

Comment: Just to learn about SQL triggers. I wanted to implement my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION trg_upbef()
  RETURN trigger as
$func$
BEGIN
IF (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM   tab
    WHERE  second = NEW.second ) > 3 THEN

   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error: there are more than 5 parts.';
END IF;

RETURN NEW;  -- must be NEW for BEFORE trigger

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER upbef
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tab
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE procedure trg_upbef();
```

#### Major points

- Keyword is `RETURNS`, not <strike>`RETURN`</strike>.
- Use the [special variable **`NEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) to refer to the newly inserted / updated row.
- Use a `BEFORE` trigger. Better skip early in case of an exception.
- Don't count *everything* for your test, just what you need. *Much* faster.
- Use [dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729). Makes your live easier.
- Concurrency:
  If you want to be absolutely sure, you'll have to take an exclusive lock on the table before counting. Else, concurrent inserts / updates might outfox each other under heavy concurrent load. While this is rather unlikely, it's possible.

Comment: Is there a reason why you put the > 3 after the if statement?

Comment: @user1871869: It isn't *after* the `IF` statement, really. Just outside the `SELECT` statement. The comparison with `count(*)` could go inside as well in this case. Would even be a very tiny bit faster. I did not enclose the whole `IF` expression in parentheses like you did. That's just noise.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thank you! I was having issues with the RETURN statement... I put return as opposed to returns..