# COPY csv using custom filename path

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, csv, plpgsql

I'm getting some issues while trying to export a query to CSV using the COPY function.

The COPY runs ok and exports the query successfully if not using custom filenames on the `TO`.

The issue is related to add a "datestamp" (kinda) to the filename created.

```
declare var1 varchar(25);
DECLARE STATEMENT TEXT;
select into var1 current_date -1;
STATEMENT := 'COPY (SELECT * from myTable) To ''E'C:\\Exports\\export_'||var1||'.csv' ''With CSV';
EXECUTE STATEMENT;
```

In this case, `var1` gets a value like `2013-12-16` and I need to add that to the filename to obtain `export_2012-12-16.csv`

I'm assuming that the `'` are misplaced. I've tried several combinations without success and off course the error is `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "C"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plpgsql code could work like this:

```
...
DECLARE
   var1 text;
BEGIN
var1 := to_char(current_date - 1, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
EXECUTE $$COPY (SELECT * from myTable)
          TO E'C:\\Exports\\export_$$ || var1 || $$.csv' WITH CSV$$;
...
```

Your quotes got tangled. Using [dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729) to simplify. Note that syntax highlighting here on SO is misleading because it does not understand dollar-quoting.

`DECLARE` is only needed once (not an error though). Plus, `BEGIN` was missing.

And `to_char()` makes the text representation of a date independent of the locale.