# Exceptions when creating a trigger in PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, stado

I use PostgreSQL 9.1 with PostGIS 1.5.

I'm trying to get this trigger function to work in terminal (Ubuntu):

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_trigger()
RETURNS trigger AS
$insert_trigger$
BEGIN
IF ( NEW.id >= 10 AND NEW.id < 100 ) THEN 
INSERT INTO part_id_p10 VALUES (NEW.*); 
ELSIF ( NEW.id >= 100 AND NEW.id < 200 ) THEN 
INSERT INTO part_id_p20 VALUES (NEW.*);
ELSE
RAISE EXCEPTION 'id out of range.  Something wrong with the insert_trigger() function!';
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END
$insert_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

i get this exceptions:

```
SQLException: ERROR: Encountered "FUNCTION" at line 1, column 8.

SQLException: ERROR: Encountered "ELSIF" at line 1, column 1.

SQLException: ERROR: Encountered "ELSE" at line 1, column 1.

SQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.

SQLException: ERROR: Encountered "RETURN" at line 1, column 1.

SQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.
```

Comment: Works here. Maybe you have a BOM in your file. Which editor did you use ?

Comment: in Linux terminal. actually i'm working on stado which is a clustered db system. all sql commands work fine except for this function.

Comment: `hexdump -c myfile.sql | head` to see if there are strange characters at the beginning of the file.

Comment: which file? i type this function direct in command line. is that okay? i also run other sql commands such as select, insert... etc. all work fine but this.

Comment: So you are working with Stado. Why is this information missing in your questions? It's the key for the solution.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I didn't even know about stado. BOM was just a shot from the hip ...

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear at first. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quote what I found in [online documentation](http://www.stormdb.com/documentation/stado/planning_guide?destination=node/19):

> Stado is written in Java and communicates with the underlying databases via **JDBC**.

Bold emphasis mine. Based on this, let me present a this hypothesis:

Many here know the website **SQL Fiddle**. It uses JDBC, too. Here is what happens when I try to create your function in default mode:

[**Failing fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1536)

But this one works:

[**Working Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1537)

The difference? I changed the "Query Terminator" (bottom right) from `;` to `//` to keep JDBC from butchering the statement. Obviously, JDBC cannot (yet) deal with [**dollar-quoting**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) correctly. See [@Craig's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747225/exceptions-when-creating-a-trigger-in-postgresql-9-1/22748778#comment34681806_22748778) below.

You can circumvent the problem by using a query terminator that does not show up in your code, like in my fiddle. Or replace dollar-quotes with plain single-quotes. You'll have to escape every single-quote properly, though:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Comment: ooh! so just replace all ';' with '//' would solve the problem?

Comment: Well, replace the respective setting for JDBC, not replace `;` in the code, which must still be valid for Postgres. That should keep JDBCC from butchering the statement at every `;`. At least this works with SQL Fiddle. I have never used Stado.

Comment: Yep, you got it: PgJDBC's parser isn't currently smart enough to deal properly with dollar-quoting. Patches welcomed.