# How to execute plpgsql anonymous block in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plpgsql

If I execute single SQL statements in worksheet (eg `CREATE ROLE my_user LOGIN PASSWORD 'my_pwd' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';`) then is works correctly. Wrapping it in anonymous block like this:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN 
  CREATE ROLE my_user LOGIN PASSWORD 'my_pwd' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
END
$$;
```

and I get following error message:

```
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
BEGIN 
  CREATE ROLE my_user LOGIN PASSWORD 'my_pwd' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
END
$$;
Error report -
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
  Position: 10
```

However, the same script works fine when I execute it in psql shell. Am I missing something obvious?

Using:
PostgreSQL version 9.4
Postgres JDBC driver postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41
SQL Developer version 4.0 (jdk 1.7.0_71)

Comment: Did you try a `/` on a single line after the block? I don't think **Oracle** SQL Developer understands Postgres' dollar quoting. So you might also try to use regular single quotes instead of `$$` (of course you need to double the embedded single quotes then)

Comment: Tried and got the same result.

Comment: Then I guess Oracle's SQL Developer is not a good choice for working with Postgres

Answer (score 1):

The source of the error is **JDBC's inability to deal with dollar-quoting** correctly (yet). Related answer:

- [Exceptions when creating a trigger in PostgreSQL 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747225/exceptions-when-creating-a-trigger-in-postgresql-9-1/22748778#22748778)

You might be able to **circumvent** the problem in this case with:

```
DO
'
BEGIN 
  CREATE ROLE my_user LOGIN PASSWORD ''my_pwd'' VALID UNTIL ''infinity'';
END
';
```

If that doesn't do the trick, try to set a **different *query terminator***, like advised in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747225/exceptions-when-creating-a-trigger-in-postgresql-9-1/22748778#22748778).

You seem to be aware that you do not need a [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement for the example code at all. Just:

```
CREATE ROLE my_user LOGIN PASSWORD 'my_pwd' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

Comment: I used single statement only for this example but actually I need to combine several statements. For example: `BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = ''my_user'') THEN CREATE ROLE my_user LOGIN PASSWORD ''my_pwd'' VALID UNTIL ''infinity''; END IF; END`. I tried what You suggested and it still didn't work  `ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"`

Comment: @Ragnar: I would then try to set a different query terminator. See added note in the answer and also the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747225/exceptions-when-creating-a-trigger-in-postgresql-9-1/22748778#22748778).