# Dollar-quotes failing with JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql, quotes

I have to write a function in PLPGSQL but I have problem with the function body quoted with dollar-quoting. Using the first tutorial:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inc(val integer) 
RETURNS integer AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN val + 1;
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I get an error:

> unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near $$

Searching on google I just found it's a JDBC Driver problem but I cannot update it.
So I have tried to change the `DELIMITER` to remove `$$`:

```
DELIMITER ++;
CREATE FUNCTION inc(val integer) 
RETURNS integer AS 
++BODY++
BEGIN
    RETURN val + 1;
END; 
++BODY++
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
DELIMITER ;
```

The command doesn't return any error but function doesn't exists when I try to call it:

```
select inc(4);
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems your SQL client can't handle the dollar quoting. Which SQL client are you using? (And the "dollar quotes" are **not**  a delimiter, they are an alternative way of [writing a string constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING))

Comment: Where does JDBC come in here?

Comment: Im using HeidiSQL

Comment: It's most certainly an issue with your client not handling `$` signs. Your function looks just fine.

Comment: Tried with pgAdmin and it works.

Comment: DBeaver also is affected by this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem is JDBC's inability to deal with dollar-quotes.
I *think* this was [fixed with JDBC version 9.4.1208 (2016-02-16)](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/9109451c65d43328b8e4344642331d7750d79cf6).

See:

- [Exceptions when creating a trigger in PostgreSQL 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747225/exceptions-when-creating-a-trigger-in-postgresql-9-1/22748778#22748778)
- [How to execute plpgsql anonymous block in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779235/how-to-execute-plpgsql-anonymous-block-in-oracle-sql-developer/27810668#27810668)

You can avoid the problem by using plain quotes for the simple case:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inc(val integer) 
  RETURNS integer AS 
'
BEGIN
   RETURN val + 1;
END 
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)