# num_rows in postgres always return 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` with Postgres.

**What I need:** Catch the rows affected by the query. It's a school system. If the student is not registered, do something (if).

**What I tried:**

```
$query = pg_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inscritossimulado
            WHERE codigo_da_escola = '".$CodEscola."'
            AND codigo_do_simulado = '".$simulado."'
            AND codigo_do_aluno = '".$aluno."'");

if(pg_num_rows($query) == 0)
{
    echo "Error you're not registered!";
}
else
{
    echo "Hello!";
}
```

**Note:** The student in question IS NOT REGISTERED, but the result is always 1 and not 0.

For some reason, when I "show" the query, the result is: "Resource id #21". But, I look many times in the table, and the user is not there.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but the query will indeed return exactly one row. You need to get the **value** returned by the query not the number of rows returned by it.

Comment: Unless you want an uncomfortable conversation with [lil' Bobby Tables' parents](http://bobby-tables.com/), read http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php . Look at PDO and parameterized statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting the number of rows in the answer, and your query always returns a single line.

Your query says: return one row giving the number of students matching my criteria.  If no one matches, you will get back one row with the value `0`.  If you have 7 people matching, you will get back one row with the value `7`.

If you change your query to `select * from ...` you will get the right answer from `pg_num_rows()`.

Comment: I would assume it's more efficient to retrieve the value of the `count(*)` instead. If for some reason the conditions return thousands of users, that will really make this slow.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, **don't count at all**. You don't need the count. Just check for existence, which is proven if a single row qualifies:

```
$query = pg_query(
  'SELECT 1
   FROM   inscritossimulado
   WHERE  codigo_da_escola = $$' . $CodEscola . '$$
   AND    codigo_do_simulado = $$' . $simulado. '$$
   AND    codigo_do_aluno = $$' . $aluno . '$$
   LIMIT  1');
```

Returns **1 row** if found, else **no row**.
Using [dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729) in the SQL code, so we can use the safer and faster single quotes in PHP (I presume).

The problem with the [aggregate function `count()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) (besides being more expensive) is that it *always* returns a row - with the value `0` if no rows qualify.

But this **still stinks**. Don't use string concatenation, which is an open invitation for **SQL injection**. Rather use prepared statements ... Check out [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) ...

Comment: Don't use dollar-quoting to enclose PHP variables. Nothing tells that these variables don't contain `$$` and that just creates a new opportunity for SQL injections, one that is not avoided by the recommended quoting method: `pg_escape_string`.

Comment: @DanielVérité: `$$` or `'`, same principal, that's why I suggested prepared statements.