# Write a query to select columns wrapped in single quotes

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoting

I am trying to write a select query which should return the column value wrapped in single quote. Say the column (ABC) has

```
Values: 123
        567
```

The query should return the

```
Output: '123'
        '567'
```

Comment: Select '\''||ABC||'\'' from table

and Select '''ABC''' from table

1st query throws an exception
nonstandard use of \' in a string literal

2nd query returns the column name in single quotes rather that the data 'ABC'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While dealing with numerical data, you can simply concatenate. NULL values stay `NULL`. But for character data (or similar) that might need escaping, use proper functions.

[`quote_nullable()` or `quote_literal()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) - depending on whether you have NULL values:

```
SELECT quote_nullable(val) AS quoted_val FROM tbl;
```

Details for quoting:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to escape the quote with another one, as in the standard SQL escape syntax:

```
nunks=# select '''I''m escaping a string''';
        ?column?         
-------------------------
 'I'm escaping a string'
(1 row)
```

When wrapping some output values, you'll have to concatenate with ||:

```
nunks=# create table numbers (number int);
CREATE TABLE

nunks=# insert into numbers values (151515);
INSERT 0 1

nunks=# select number from numbers;
 number 
--------
 151515
(1 row)

nunks=# select ''''||number||'''' from numbers;
 ?column? 
----------
 '151515'
(1 row)
```

Maybe you'll find it clearer using the [E syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE):

```
nunks=# select E'\''||number||E'\'' from numbers;
 ?column? 
----------
 '151515'
(1 row)
```