# How to strip comments starting at ** line form text in sql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Postgres 8.3+  database text column contains possible multi line expression.

After expression there and be empty lines and comment area.
Comment  area starts with ** characters at start of line.
There can be only empty lines in end of expression

Examples

```
1+
2
** this
is comment
```

With trailine extra newline:

```
1+
2

** this
is comment and newline after expression
```

How to strip empty lines and comments from expression?
Empty lines inside expression shoudl replaced to spaces. Empty lines and comments at end of expression should stripped. Result should be `1+ 2` in both cases.
If there is only comment, empty string should returned.

I tried method below but this does not replace newlines inside expression with spaces. How to fix ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.RemoveComment(value text) RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
select case when tulem like '**%' then ''
  else tulem end
from (  
SELECT trim(lower( Translate(   regexp_replace($1, E'\n\\*\\*.*', '', 'g'),E'\n\r', '')    )) as tulem
) tulem;

$BODY$ language sql immutable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the replace twice if you want to remove comments and replace newlines with spaces inside text:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace($1, '((\n*)(\*\*.*)?)$', ''),'\n',' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't test in Postgres 8.3, that's just too old and not available to me any more. But this should work - it does in Postgres 9.3.

```
SELECT regexp_replace($1, '[ \n]*\*\*.*$', '');
```

With [`standard_conforming_strings = on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS)! More:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb/311)

#### Explain

`[ \n\r]` .. character class of space, newline and carriage return. You may not need `\r`, depending on your strings ..
`*`  .. any number or times
`\*\*` .. two literal stars
`.*` .. any characters, any number of time
`$` .. end of string

Comment: if value contains only newlines at end, this will not remove those newlines.