# How to change double quote to single quote from psql prompt

Tags: postgresql, quotes, psql

I'm trying to execute an UPDATE from a psql prompt. I want to change all instances of a country name from `Cote d"Ivoire` to `Cote d'Ivoire` (so the double quote becomes a single quote). My first attempt did nothing but change the psql prompt (notice the double quote between the database name and the pound character)...

`database=# UPDATE address SET country = 'Cote d\'Ivoire' WHERE country = 'Cote D"Ivoire';
database"#`

...so I escaped the double quote and got an error:

`database=# UPDATE address SET country = 'Cote d\'Ivoire' WHERE country = 'Cote D\"Ivoire';
Invalid command \"Ivoire';. Try \? for help.`

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

I used [dollar-quoted string constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to achieve what I wanted:

`database=# UPDATE address SET country = $$Cote d'Ivoire$$ WHERE country = $$Cote D"Ivoire$$;
UPDATE 22`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using escapes in strings, you need to use the escaped string syntax. Put a capital E before your single quote. See this thorough answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/1413900