# Complex concatenation of columns into one column

Tags: postgresql, null, case, string-concatenation

I have this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE
    WHEN abc > def THEN 'abc is larger than def'::text
    ELSE NULL::text
END AS case1,
CASE
    WHEN abc < ghi THEN 'def is larger than abc'::text
    ELSE NULL::text
END AS case2,
CASE 
    WHEN abc > jkl THEN 'abc is larger than jkl'::text
    ELSE NULL::text
END AS case3,
```

This looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|              case1          |           case2          |          case3           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    'abc is larger than def' | 'def is larger than abc' | 'abc is larger than jkl' |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to do is to create a column called `'casesCombined'`, than would combine 'then's'. For example, if top 2 cases are true, then column `'casesCombined'` would be `'"abc is larger than def", "def is larger than abc"'`.

Like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|                  casesCombined                    |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 'abc is larger than def', 'def is larger than abc'|
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Tried many ways, not able to figure out. I also don't need those `'case1'`, `'case2'`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT concat_ws(', ', CASE WHEN abc > def THEN 'abc is larger than def' END
                     , CASE WHEN abc < ghi THEN 'def is larger than abc' END
                     , CASE WHEN abc > jkl THEN 'abc is larger than jkl' END
                ) AS cases_combined
FROM tbl;
```

`CASE` defaults to NULL when there is not `ELSE` clause.
`concat_ws()` ignores NULL values.

I did not add extra single-quotes since I assume you did not actually want those in the result. Just add if you do:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)