# Postgres replacing 'text' with e'text'

Tags: postgresql

I inserted a bunch of rows with a text field like `content='...\n...\n...'`.

I didn't use `e` in front, like `conent=e'...\n...\n...`, so now `\n` is not actually displayed as a newline - it's printed as text.

How do I fix this, i.e. how to change every row's content field from `'...'` to `e'...'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax variant `E'string'` makes Postgres interpret the given string as  Posix escape string. `\n` encoding a newline is only one of many interpreted escape sequences (even if the most common one). See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

To "re-evaluate" your Posix escape string, you could use a simple function with dynamic SQL like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_eval_posix_escapes(INOUT _string text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT E''' || _string || ''''  INTO _string;
END
$func$;
```

**WARNING 1:** This is inherently **unsafe**! We have to evaluate input strings dynamically without quoting and escaping, which allows **SQL injection**. Only use this in a safe environment.

**WARNING 2:** Don't apply repeatedly. Or it will misinterpret your actual string with genuine `\` characters, etc.

**WARNING 3:** This simple function is imperfect as it cannot cope with **nested single quotes** properly. If you have some of those, consider instead:

- [Unescape a string with escaped newlines and carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867637/unescape-a-string-with-escaped-newlines-and-carriage-returns/35237937#35237937)

Apply:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    content = f_eval_posix_escapes(content)
WHERE  content IS DISTINCT FROM f_eval_posix_escapes(content);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6477ccaf1fddacd6d12b68f90db23edf)*

Note the added `WHERE` clause to skip updates that would not change anything. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Answer (score 2):

Use REPLACE in an update query. Something like this: (I'm on mobile so please ignore any typo or syntax erro)

```
UPDATE table
SET 
column = REPLACE(column, '\n', e'\n')
```

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! But is \n the only difference between e'...' and '...'? For example, if I had tabs, I'd have to repeat this for e'\t', right? Is there a way to do the whole thing in one go?

Comment: Also, I can't edit it, but in Postgres there should be "FROM" after UPDATE, just UPDATE table...

Comment: I don't think so. You have to replace one by one.

Comment: @Carbs: The `FROM` clause is optional in an `UPDATE`, to join in additional relations,  and not needed in the example.