# postgresql escaped quotes still escaped in DB

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, psql

Just had to import some data in my postgreSQL db with sometimes single quote escapes. 
Everything is fine, but at the end I still have my '' escapes in my DB values.

before import : `L'Auberge D'Aillane`

after import (when I do a "SELECT name from mytable") : `L''Auberge D''Aillane`

is that normal ? is there any way to have to right value in the entries ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed answer here:
[Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql)

But as quick response use the backslash escape instead of double quotes:
In old versions or if you still run with standard_conforming_strings = off or, generally, if you prepend your string with E to declare Posix escape string syntax, you can also escape with the backslash :

```
E'user\'s log'
```

Comment: i'm in psql 9.4.5 so double quotes escaping should be running well, no ?
i don't want to user E escape as it's not supported no and standard_conforming_strings should be on.

Answer (score 0):

As you logged your question here also: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1020

The answer is the very same:

> as you see I use the double-quote escape to avoid any insertion error

You shouldn't be doing that ever! The `node-postgres` library's internal formatting provides the correct escaping for strings as well as all the other JavaScript types.