# PL/pgSQL to copy data from tables dynamically

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4, string-interpolation

I'm trying to write some SQL to copy data from all of my PostgreSQL tables in a given database based on what's in the information_schema. It should output data files to my local machine ready for import to another machine. Ultimately, I'm going to tweak this so that I dump only select portions of tables (some of the tables I'm dumping have millions of records and I only want a small subset of data for testing purposes).

Here's what I have so far...

```
--Copy all tables...
DO
$$
DECLARE
    formatstring text;
    rec record;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Copying tables...';
    formatstring = 'COPY (select * from %I) to ''C:\Media\Code\%s.csv'';';
    FOR rec IN 
        select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public' order by table_name
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table: %', rec.table_name;
        RAISE NOTICE format(formatstring, rec.table_name, rec.table_name);
        EXECUTE format(formatstring, rec.table_name, rec.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, I am getting this exception...

> ```
> ERROR:  unrecognized exception condition "format"
> CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "inline_code_block" near line 12
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: unrecognized exception condition "format"
> SQL state: 42704
> Context: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "inline_code_block" near line 12
> ```

The escaping of the single quotes seems fine (already checked this question: [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql)). Indeed I can do the following and it works, with text being inserted into the formatting:

```
select format('COPY (select * from %I) to ''C:\Media\Code\%s.csv'';', 'system_user', 'system_user');
```

Can anyone assist with this issue? I can easily write a script or code that will generate the copy commands for me, but it would be great to do it all within a simple bit of SQL.

Comment: It's a rare and pleasant to see a question like it should be: All the essential information and a minimum of noise, clearly presented. Chapeau!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is a syntax error in your 3nd `RAISE` statement. There are [several valid formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE), but you cannot feed an *expression* to `RAISE` directly. It has to be a string literal - with the option of string interpolation.

While being at it, simplify a couple of other things:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
   _tbl text;
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Copying tables...';
   
   FOR _tbl IN 
      SELECT table_name
      FROM   information_schema.tables
      WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
      ORDER  BY table_name
   LOOP
      _sql := format($$COPY %1$I TO 'C:\Media\Code\%1$s.csv'$$, _tbl);
      RAISE NOTICE 'Table: %', _tbl;
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;            -- fixed!
      EXECUTE _sql;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

- Use the plain table name with [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) instead of `SELECT * FROM tbl`.
- Use nested [dollar-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860).
- Format specifiers [`%1$I` and `%1$s` for the `format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function, so we only need to supply the table name once.
- Use a scalar variable instead of a `record` in the `FOR` loop - we only need the one column anyway.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you very much for the assist. I have two additional issues: I want to include the table_catalog in the output filename and I'm going to want to limit certain tables based on conditional statements to a certain range of data rather than the whole table, only for certain tables. Or to explain better, I want to copy all the static data tables with limited records, but I only want a subset of data from the larger tables. I can look into this myself though or ask another question. Your help has been very much appreciated :)

Comment: @ManoDestra: Yes, this sounds like another question. Too much for a comment. You can always link to this one for context.