# Seemingly incorrect regex evaluation in regexp_replace

Tags: regex, postgresql

I just stumbled upon a curious behavior of `regexp_replace` PostgreSQL function. It looks like a bug but I always doubt myself first. When I run

```
SELECT regexp_replace(E'1%2_3', '([_%])', E'\\ \\1', 'g')
```

it correctly prefixes either underscore or percent with backslash+space and produces "`1\ %2\ _3`". However when I remove space (it doesn't have to be space, can be any character)

```
SELECT regexp_replace(E'1%2_3', '([_%])', E'\\\\1', 'g')
```

it stops using captured parenthesized expression in substitution and produces "`1\12\13`" instead of "`1\%2\_3`". I would appreciate if someone could tell me what am I doing wrong. I simply need to add backslash before certain characters in a string.

**UPDATE**: I was able to achieve the desired behavior by running

```
SELECT regexp_replace(E'1%2_3', '([_%])', E'\\\\\\1', 'g')
```

My original example still seems a bit illogical and inconsistent. The inconsistency is that using the same `E'...'` syntax 4 backslashes may produce different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second query, after the backslash escapES are processed at the string level, you have the replacement string `\\1`.

What's happening is that the escaped backslash prevents `\1` from being recognized as a back-reference. You need another set of backslashes, so that the replacement string is `\\\1` to get a literal backslash and a back-reference. Since every literal backslash needs to be escaped, you need to double all of them.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(E'1%2_3', '([_%])', E'\\\\\\1', 'g')
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar I just discovered this myself after a few more experiments

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the outdated Posix escape syntax in Postgres without need in the first place. Are you running an outdated version with `standard_conforming_strings = off`? Because if you are not, simplify:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('1%2_3', '([_%])', '\\\1', 'g')
```

You only need to add a single `\` to escape the special meaning of `\` in the regexp pattern.

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Strings prefixed with `E` have to be processed, which costs a tiny bit extra and there is always the risk of unintended side effects with special characters. It's pointless to write `E'1%2_3'` for a string you want to provide *as is*. Make that just `'1%2_3'` in any case.

---

And for just just two characters to replace simple use:

```
SELECT replace(replace('1%2_3', '_', '\_'), '%', '\%')
```

Regular expressions are powerful, but for a price. Even several nested simple `replace()` calls are cheaper than a single `regexp_replace()`.

Comment: I had this thought about regex vs replace before but didn't give it much of significance. Thanks!