# Single quotes stored in a Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, express, quotes, pg-dump, postgresql-copy

I've been working on an Express app that has a form designed to hold lines and quotes.

Some of the lines will have single quotes(`'`), but overall it's able to store the info and I'm able to back it up and store it without any problems. Now, when I want do `pg_dump` and have the database put into an SQL file, the quotes seem to cause some things to appear a bit wonky in my text editor.

Would I have to create a method to change all the single quotation marks into double, or can I leave it as is and be able to upload it back to the database without causing major issues. I know people will continue to enter in lines that contain either single or double quotations, so I would like to know any solution or answer that would help greatly.

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes in character data types are **no problem at all**. You just need to escape them properly in string literals.

To write data with [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) you need to quote all string literals according to SQL syntax rules. There are tools to do that for you ...

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

**However**, `pg_dump` takes care of escaping automatically. The default mode produces text output to be re-imported with **`COPY`** (much faster than `INSERT`), and single quotes have no special meaning there. And in (non-default) `csv` mode, the default quote character is double-quote (`"`) and configurable. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

> `QUOTE`
>
> Specifies the quoting character to be used when a data value is quoted. The default is double-quote. This must be a single one-byte character. This option is allowed only when using `CSV` format.

The format is defined by rules for `COPY` and not by SQL syntax rules.