# Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL 9.4.3

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Using this: 
[Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql)

I run on Postgres version 9.4.3 with command sql after

```
insert into test values (1,$$user's log$$);
```

Postgres returns error message

```
ERROR: 42601: Syntax error at or near "s"
```

Comment: Dollar quoting like that should work. Which tool do you use to run that statement?

Comment: I run on Query pgAdmin III