# How to avoid syntax error when returning text which includes a BEGIN statement in it?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, quotes

I'm trying to build a function that returns some text. The text includes a `BEGIN` statement which seems to cause an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_trigger() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN
    'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_view() RETURNS trigger AS $$
       BEGIN -- error is near this begin
        IF TG_OP = ''INSERT''  THEN DO SOMETHING;
        ELSIF TG_OP = ''UPDATE'' THEN DO SOMETHING;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
       END;
    $$ language plpgsql';
END;
$$ language plpgsql
```

I get a syntax error near the word `BEGIN` in the return statement and don't understand why, as I'm only trying to return some text. Is this because `plpgsql` recognizes the word `BEGIN` even if it is in a string portion of the code?

Comment: Could you try to add a `;` after `END;`

Comment: Does not work either (edited the post with this modification)

Comment: The begin isn't causing the error, it's the nested `$$`.  Use a different delimiter for the quoted function.

Comment: Oh it works when using $BODY$ in the quoted function instead of $$. Post this as an answer !

Comment: About quoting and dollar-quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729

Answer (score 0):

Like [user3137702 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267405/how-to-avoid-syntax-error-when-returning-text-which-includes-a-begin-statement-i/41294167#comment69736055_41267405), the problem is with the dollar-quotes. I'd also suggest some other simplifications:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_trigger()
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT
   $f$CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_view()
        RETURNS trigger AS
      $func1$
      BEGIN
       CASE TG_OP
         WHEN 'INSERT' THEN -- DO SOMETHING;
         WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN -- DO SOMETHING;
       END CASE;
       RETURN NEW;
      END;
      $func1$ LANGUAGE plpgsql$f$;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

About quoting and nested dollar-quotes:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)