# Filter strings with regex before casting to numeric

Tags: regex, postgresql, casting, numeric

I have this code (was already there, isn't mine):

```
SELECT
    a.id_original_contrato AS contrato,
    ( CASE WHEN d.value~'^\\d+$' THEN d.value::integer ELSE 0 END ) AS monto,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM b.value)::integer AS anoinicio,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c.value)::integer AS anofin
```

... etc (some JOIN's and WHERE's)

Let me explain: `d.value` comes from a table where value is `character varying (200)`. The code will insert later the `d.value` (now called 'monto') in another table as a `integer`. Someone coded that regex in order to extract some chars or in other case (ELSE), define it as 0. Those values works when they are `integer` only. If I use a d.value like `76.44` it doesn't work due that regex, it always define it as 0.

Well, I have to change that code, because:

- I need to store the d.value in the new table as `numeric`, not as `integer` anymore (In my new table the data type is `numeric` now)
- But first, I need to correct that regex, because is messing my numeric numbers like `76.44`, or `66,56` (dot or coma).

I'm not sure what that regex is doing. And how could I accomplish what need with a better or new regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double backslash in `\\d` suggests an old version with `standard_conforming_strings = off`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS)

> Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is `on` (prior releases defaulted to off).

In modern versions with `standard_conforming_strings = on`, this string makes little sense as regular expression: <strike>`'^\\d+$'`</strike>. To detect strings consisting of one or more digits use either `E'^\\d+$'` (prefixed with `E`) or `'^\d+$'`. Details:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Integer literals also allow an optional **leading sign** for negative / positive numbers, and leading / dangling **white space** in Postgres.
So, this is the complete regular expression for valid `integer` literals:

```
CASE WHEN d.value ~ '^\s*[-+]?\d+\s*$' THEN d.value::int ELSE 0 END
```

The regular expression explained:

`^` .. start of string
`\s` .. [class shorthand](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) for `[[:space:]]` (white space)
`*` .. [quantifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE) for 0 or more times
`[+-]` .. character class consisting of `+` and `-`
`?` .. quantifier for 0 or 1 times
`\d` .. class shorthand for `[[:digit:]]` (digits)
`+` .. quantifier for 1 or more times
`\s*` .. same as above
`$` .. end of string

Consider the syntax rules for [numeric string literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC). One essential quote:

> There cannot be any spaces or other characters embedded in the constant

That's because a numeric constant is not quoted, hence white space is not possible. Not applicable for *casting* strings. White space is *tolerated*:

> Leading, trailing and right after the exponent char.

So these are all legal strings for the cast to `numeric`:

**`'^\s*[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE]\s*[-+]?\d+)?\s*$'`**

The only new element are [parentheses (`()`) to denote the contained regular expression as *atom*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE). Since we are not interested in back references, use  "non-capturing": `(?:`...`)` and append a question mark `(?:[eE]\s*[-+]?\d+)?` to mean: the "exponential" part can be added or not, *as a whole*.

Assuming dot (`.`) as decimal separator. You might use comma instead (`,`) or `[,\.]` to allow either. But only dot is legal for the cast.

Test:

```sql
SELECT '|' || lit || '|' AS text_with_delim
     , lit ~ '^\s*[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE]\s*[-+]?\d+)?\s*$' AS valid
     , lit::numeric AS number
FROM   unnest ('{1
               , 123
               , 000
               , "  -1     "
               , +2
               , 1.2
               , .34
               , 5e6
               , " .5e   -6  "
                }'::text[]) lit;
```

Result:

| text_with_delim | valid | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| |1| | t | 1 |
| |123| | t | 123 |
| |000| | t | 0 |
| | -1 | | t | -1 |
| |+2| | t | 2 |
| |1.2| | t | 1.2 |
| |.34| | t | 0.34 |
| |5e6| | t | 5000000 |
| | .5e -6 | | t | 0.0000005 |

---

Or you might have use for [`to_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to convert strings of arbitrary *given* format.

Comment: I see, hmm. The coded is made to work in 9.2, and now it will run in 9.4. I'm still reading and trying to get your answer. Thanks (+1)

Comment: Great, only by using the '^\s*[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE]\s*[-+]?\d+)?\s*$' regex I can make it works! My Postgresql is set to US in postgresql.conf like this: `lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'` so by now I can only use `.` as decimal separator, but in production enviroment is set as `lc_numeric = 'es_ES.UTF-8' ` so i think I won't have problems there. I'll keep reading and doing all what you have written here Erwin, thanks you.

Comment: @pmirnd: `lc_numeric` influences the behavior of functions like `to_char()`, but the the *type cast* from `text` to `numeric` does *not* depend on locale settings. That would be madness. So, a comma is never legal in a *cast* to numeric. You'll have to replace it with `replace()` or `translate()`. Or use `to_number()`.

Comment: Finally, what I did and now works ok is: `select cast(replace(d.value, ',', '.') as numeric) AS monto` . ta-da!

Answer (score 2):

Choose a variant:

```
with v(value) as (
    values
    ('12,3'),
    ('12.3'),
    ('123'),
    ('123.'),
    ('.123'),
    ('1.2.3')
    )

select 
    value, 
    value ~ '^(\d+[,\.]\d+|\d+)$' as variant_a,
    value ~ '^(\d*[,\.]\d*|\d+)$' as variant_b,
    value ~ '^\d+[,\.]\d+$' as variant_c
from v;

 value | variant_a | variant_b | variant_c 
-------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 12,3  | t         | t         | t
 12.3  | t         | t         | t
 123   | t         | t         | f
 123.  | f         | t         | f
 .123  | f         | t         | f
 1.2.3 | f         | f         | f
(6 rows)
```

To convert a string with a dot or a comma to numeric use `replace()`:

```
select replace(value, ',', '.')::numeric;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I put a +1 to this because I learnt something that I didn't knew.