# Get group maxima from combined strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group, string-parsing

I have a table with a column `code` containing multiple pieces of data like this:

```
001/2017/TT/000001
001/2017/TT/000002
001/2017/TN/000003
001/2017/TN/000001
001/2017/TN/000002
001/2016/TT/000001
001/2016/TT/000002
001/2016/TT/000001
002/2016/TT/000002
```

There are 4 items in `001/2016/TT/000001`: `001`,  `2016`, `TT` and `000001`.
How can I extract the max for every group formed by the first 3 items? The result I want is this:

```
001/2017/TT/000003
001/2017/TN/000002
001/2016/TT/000002
002/2016/TT/000002
```

**Edit**

- The subfield separator is `/`, and the length of subfields can vary.
- I use PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: Is the subfield length constant? Or just the separator '/'?

Comment: no, just a separator `/` @ErwinBrandstetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you should **normalize** the table and split the combined string into 4 columns with proper data type. The function [**`split_part()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) is the tool of choice if the separator `'/'`  is constant in your string and the length of can vary.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_better AS 
SELECT split_part(code, '/', 1)::int AS col_1  -- better names?
     , split_part(code, '/', 2)::int AS col_2
     , split_part(code, '/', 3)      AS col_3  -- text?
     , split_part(code, '/', 4)::int AS col_4
FROM   tbl_bad
ORDER  BY 1,2,3,4  -- optionally cluster data.
```

Then the task is trivial:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, max(col_4) AS max_nr
FROM   tbl_better
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Related:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

Of course, you *can* do it on the fly, too. For varying subfield length you could use [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) with a regular expression like this:

```
SELECT max(substring(code, '([^/]*)$')) AS max_nr
FROM   tbl_bad
GROUP  BY substring(code, '^(.*)/');
```

Related (with basic explanation for regexp pattern):

- [Filter strings with regex before casting to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214084/filter-strings-with-regex-before-casting-to-numeric/42216764#42216764)

Or to get only the complete string as result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (substring(code, '^(.*)/'))
       code
FROM   tbl_bad
ORDER  BY substring(code, '^(.*)/'), code DESC;
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Be aware that data items cast to a suitable type *may* behave differently from their string representation. The max of `900001` and `1000001` is `900001` for `text` and `1000001` for `integer` ...

Comment: Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter i think this should help me, i need something, i want to select all the code `001/2017/TT/000003` to insert it into another table, your query gives me just the last part `000003`

Comment: @YCF_L: I added another solution. Now with the missing `DESC` in `ORDER BY` to get the max.

Comment: hoho Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter, the second solution work soo good, some clarification the second one work until there columns not contain the same separator and this is more good, thank youu :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions.

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(code,6)) AS MAX_CODE
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY LEFT(code,12)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out, possible helpfull

```
select 
distinct on (tab[4],tab[2]) tab[4],tab[3],tab[2],tab[1]
from
(
    select
    string_to_array(exe.x,'/') as tab,
    exe.x
    from
    (
        select
        unnest
            (
            array
            ['001/2017/TT/000001',
            '001/2017/TT/000002',
            '001/2017/TN/000003',
            '001/2017/TN/000001',
            '001/2017/TN/000002',
            '001/2016/TT/000001',
            '001/2016/TT/000002',
            '001/2016/TT/000001',
            '002/2016/TT/000002']
            ) as x
    ) exe
) exe2
order by tab[4] desc,tab[2] desc,tab[3] desc;
```