# How to execute a dynamic query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to execute the following dynamic sql, but I could not figure out how to do it:

```
DROP FUNCTION f_mycross(text, text);

EXECUTE ('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_mycross(text, text)
   RETURNS TABLE ("registration_id" integer, '
   || (SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT pivot_headers, ',' order by pivot_headers)
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT '"' || qid::text || '" text' AS pivot_headers
             FROM answers) x)
   || ') AS ''$libdir/tablefunc'',''crosstab_hash'' LANGUAGE C STABLE STRICT;')
```

I am relatively new to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Show us the complete code of the function that runs the dynamic SQL.

Comment: `execute` (dynymic SQL) can't be used outside of a PL/pgSQL function or `DO` block.

Comment: This is the complete code.  This code creates a dynamic crosstalk function that pivots the answers table.  Answers tables has three columns (survey_id int, question_id int, answer text).  Desired output of the function would be (survey_id, answer to question 1, answer to question 2, etc).  What is between the () builds the create statement for my dynamic function perefectly...I just want to execute it instead of selecting and then copy/pasting it form results window into the SQL window and then running it to create the function

Comment: As I said: you need to put that into a `DO` block. You can't do that in "plain SQL"

Answer (score 5):

`EXECUTE` is not an SQL command. It's a PL/pgSQL command and can only be used in a code block of that procedural language. Like:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_mycross(text, text);

DO
$do$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_mycross(text, text)
             RETURNS TABLE (registration_id integer, '
       || string_agg(pivot_header || ' text', ', ')
       || $c$) AS '$libdir/tablefunc', 'crosstab_hash' LANGUAGE C STABLE STRICT$c$
   FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT quote_ident(qid::text) AS pivot_header FROM answers ORDER BY 1) x
   );
END
$do$;  -- LANGUAGE plpgsql is the default
```

I added some improvements and simplified the nested `SELECT` query.

#### Major points

- Add [`IF EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropfunction.html) to `DROP FUNCTION` unless you are certain the function exists or you want to raise an exception if it does not.
- `DISTINCT` in the subquery is enough, no need for another `DISTINCT` in the outer `SELECT`.
- Use `quote_ident()` to automatically double-quote identifiers where necessary. Else you are open to syntax errors and SQL injection.
- No parentheses required around the string we feed to `EXECUTE`.
- Simpler nested quoting with dollar-quotes:

  - [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)
- We can apply `ORDER BY` in the subquery, which is typically much faster than adding `ORDER BY` in the outer aggregate function.