# Replace apostrophe in string

Tags: postgresql

How do i replace a single apostrophe `'` in a string ie;

Turn King's lynn to Kings lynn

Something like

`select replace ('King's lynn',''','')`

Have tried `''\'` but doesn't escape

Comment: It's `'\''`, not `''\'`. That is, the escape character (``\``) preceeds the character being escaped (`'`).

Comment: I should note that escape quoting like this in PostgreSQL [requires an `E` prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE), such as ``E'\''``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) makes it easier:

```
replace ($$King's lynn$$, $$'$$, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two single quotes to escape the character.  In your case it would mean 4 quotes in a row.

```
select replace ('King''s lynn','''','')
```

...or...

```
select replace ('King\'s lynn','\'','')
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use CHR() for apostrophe manipulation as it doesn't require learning a new syntax in each DB language...

```
REPLACE('King's lynn', CHR(39), CHR(39)||CHR(39))
```