# How can I replace the 'S for a 's in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have  a table with  large amount of 'S wrongly added and I want to replace it for 's:

I have tried with `replace(field, ''S', ''s')` but obviously doesn't accept it for the ', I also tried with the $$'$$ but still doesn't work.

The current version of PostgreSQL is 11 I have look into different threads and tried the solution there but didn't recognize i.e.

[Replace apostrophe in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758536/replace-apostrophe-in-string)

Comment: try this : `replace(field, E'\'S', E'\'s')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote is the escape character for quotes as well. So you need one more quote for each string: `replace(field, '''S', '''s')`

Comment: that nail it, thanks