# How to prevent 'invalid input syntax for type json' in Postgres, when records contain a mix of json or strings

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a text column that contains JSON and also plan text.  I want to convert it to JSON, and then select a particular property.  For example:

```
user_data
_________
{"user": {"name": "jim"}}
{"user": {"name": "sally"}}
some random data string
```

I've tried:

```
select user_data::json#>'{user,name}' from users
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "some" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON user_data, line 1: some...
```

Is it possible to prevent this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to skip the rows with invalid JSON, you must first **test** if the text is valid JSON. You can do this by creating a function which will attempt to parse the value, and catch the exception for invalid JSON values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_json(input_text varchar) RETURNS boolean AS $$
  DECLARE
    maybe_json json;
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      maybe_json := input_text;
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
    END;

    RETURN TRUE;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

When you have that, you could use the `is_json` function in a `CASE` or `WHERE` clause to narrow down the valid values.

```
-- this can eliminate invalid values
SELECT user_data::json #> '{user,name}'
FROM users WHERE is_json(user_data);

-- or this if you want to fill will NULLs
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN is_json(user_data)
      THEN user_data::json #> '{user,name}'
    ELSE
      NULL
  END
FROM users;
```

Comment: this might be helpful as well
```to_json(value)```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47873103/2878821

Comment: I still got errors with `maybe_json := input_text;` so I used `PERFORM input_text::json #>> '{}';` instead and everything works.

Answer (score 13):

Use this function:

```
create or replace function is_json(text)
returns boolean language plpgsql immutable as $$
begin
    perform $1::json;
    return true;
exception
    when invalid_text_representation then 
        return false;
end $$;
```

Test:

```
with users(user_data) as (
values
    ('{"user": {"name": "jim"}}'),
    ('not json'),
    ('{"user": {"name": "sally"}}'),
    ('also not json')
)

select user_data::json#>'{user,name}' as name
from users
where is_json(user_data);

  name   
---------
 "jim"
 "sally"
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

Others have already suggested ways to check if the JSON is valid, but I feel that rather than check that, why not already cast it?
I use this function (JSONB, but you can easily change it to JSON):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION safe_cast_to_jsonb(input TEXT) RETURNS JSONB AS
$$
DECLARE
    output JSONB DEFAULT NULL;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        output := input::JSONB;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE NOTICE 'INVALID JSONB';
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
    RETURN output;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to do a preselect for solving this issue.

Let's say we got a given table `users` with columns `id` and `user_data`. `user_data` is declared as a text field, it should contain `{firstName, lastName}` usually.

- Note that Postgres JSON operations work fine, if a given field is *NULL* - so you could omit the *WHERE* in the following statement for still selecting the rows which contain an invalid JSON in `user_data` (while the result set would only contain the `id` field in such a row)
- `user_data ~ '^{.*}$'` ("curly brace check") checks if JSON in contained in the `user_data` field. **Danger!** Bear in mind that this check is incomplete. Incorrect JSON such as '{"key1": "value1", "key2"}' is still recognised as valid
- Consider impacts on database performance

Gives as an example:

```
WITH users_json_data AS (
  SELECT 
    id,
    CASE WHEN user_data ~ '^{.*}$' THEN user_data::json END AS user_json
  FROM users
)
SELECT id, users_json_data.user_json->>firstName, users_json_data.user_json->>lastName
FROM users
INNER JOIN users_json_data USING (id)
WHERE users_json_data.user_json IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution which has a better performance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_json(inp text)
    RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE 'plperl' IMMUTABLE
AS $BODY$
# use JSON; # you need to preload this or use plperlu
my ($in) = @_;
my $chr  = substr($in, 0, 1);

return 'f' if $chr ne '[' && $chr ne '{';

eval {
    decode_json($in);
};

return $@ ? 'f' : 't';
$BODY$;
```

But of course you need to be familiar with plplerl to use this version.

If I run the query:

```
explain analyze select is_json(val) from mytable
```

this version has an execution time of about 7 ms as opposed to klin's plpgsql function which runs for about 12ms. The table had 3542 rows at the moment of testing. Plpgsql's exception handling blocks are costly to use, so avoid them when you can.