# Can an integer column be null?

Tags: postgresql, null, integer, quotes, postgresql-9.3

I made an `integer` column that is `null` by default but when I put empty double quotes `""` it gives this error:

> ```
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
> ```

Does the `integer` column have to be `0` then?

I am using Java to send the query to the database.

Comment: This question should provide the table definition and the actual `INSERT` statement used.

Answer (score 18):

An integer column can be null, but `''` is an empty string not null.  The right syntax for a null integer (or any other sql type) is `null`.

Comment: I also have tried typing the word null it self, with and without quotes but still an error.

Answer (score 8):

Double quotes can be used to delimit *identifiers*, like `"myColumnName"`.
Single quotes are used to delimit *values* in *string literals*, like `'my string literal'`.
For `integer` values you typically use *numeric constants* to input values, which are not quoted at all, like `123`. (But you *can* cast a string literal, too.)
Numeric data types (`integer`, `numeric`, `double precision`, ...) cannot store empty strings (`''`), only string types (`text`, `varchar`, ...) can.
To pass a null value, use the key word `null`. Or omit the column *completely* from your `INSERT` statement. If you did not define a different column default, it defaults to `null` automatically.

The double quotes you see in the error message are just delimiters added by Postgres for the purpose of the error message, meaning you passed an empty string (`''`). If you had actually passed

> empty double quotes ""

(which would require to be single-quoted in turn: `'""'`), you would see this error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: """"
> ```

Not sure how Java plays into this.

Consider the chapter [Lexical Structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) in the Postgres manual.

Related:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)