# Dynamic queries with knex-postgis

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I am building a simple API that also deal with geometries (store into postGIS). 
I am using knex-postgis to access the ST_ spatial functions in postGIS with knex.

I have used this example to insert a point and it work when its hard coded. 
But my lack of experience is leave me hanging, how can I make the query dynamic? I want to create a form with input for x and y value and send it to the ST_geomFromText function to save it to the geom type in the db. 
Is this when  you would use parameters? Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
// insert a point
const sql1 = db.insert({
  id: 1,
  geom: st.geomFromText('Point(0 0)', 4326)
}).into('points').toString();
console.log(sql1);
// insert into "points" ("geom", "id") values 
(ST_geomFromText('Point(0 0)'), '1')
```

So far I have tried

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  queries.create(req.body).then(poi => {
    res.json(poi[0]);
  });
});
```

Insert query

```
  create(poi) {
    const sql = db.insert(poi).returning('*').into('poi');
    return sql;
  },
```

In Postman I am sending this in its body

```
{
    "place": "test",
    "comments": "new",
    "numbers": 6,
    "geom": "st.geomFromText('Point(-71.064544 44.28787)', 4326)"
}
```

But get an error "Unhandled rejection error: parse error - invalid geometry"
The hard coded object looks the same and is work fine.

I have a feeling that I am using the st.geomFromText wrong, but i dont I am not sure?

This is what i get if i console.log returned query

```
insert into "poi" ("comments", "geom", "numbers", "place") values ('new', 'st.geomFromText(''Point(-71.064544 44.28787)'', 4326)', 6, 'test')
```

(see how it does not change st.geom.. to st_geom..? Also the quotation marks around the ST function and the Point object is not right)

This  string work when I run it in pgAdmin

```
insert into "poi" ("comments", "geom", "numbers", "place") values ('new', st_GeomFromText('Point(-71.064544 44.28787)', 4326), 6, 'test')
```

EDIT:
I console.log the hardcoded version too. It does no appear to add the extra '' on the geometry value

```
insert into "poi" ("geom") values (ST_geomFromText('Point(-71.064544 44.28787)', 4326))
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass coordinates from postman **as string value in JSON object**

```
"geom": "st.geomFromText('Point(-71.064544 44.28787)', 4326)"
```

And expect your code to transform it into a **function call**

```
st.geomFromText('Point(-71.064544 44.28787)', 4326)
```

What `knex` does in this case. It takes your **string** and convert it as it is **string** field (here you get a single quote `'` replacement with double `''` for Postgres to [escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/1162326)).

What you can do. Pass your geometry to your API like this

```
"geom": "Point(-71.064544 44.28787)"
```

And in your route handler

```
create(poi) {
  const sql = db.insert({
    place: poi.place,
    comments: poi.comments,
    numbers: poi.numbers,
    geom: st.geomFromText(poi.geom, 4326)
  }).returning('*').into('poi');
  return sql;
},
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, really helped me out! Apparently still have much to learn