# Regular expression exclusion in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have to split some string in **PostgreSQL** on `','` but not on `'\,'` (backslash is escape character).
For example, `regexp_split_to_array('123,45,67\,89', ???)` must split the string to array `{123, 45, "67\,89"}`.

What done already: `E'(?<!3),'` works with `'3'` as escape character. But how can I use the backslash instead of 3?

Does not work:

`E'(?<!\),'` does not split the string at all

`E'(?<!\\),'` throws error "parentheses () not balanced"

`E'(?<!\ ),'` (with space) splits on all `','` including `'\,'`

`E'(?<!\\ ),'` (with space) splits on all `','` too.

Comment: Is a literal backslash escaped in the input? What is the expected output for `'123,45,67\\,89'`?

Comment: Please *always* declare your version of Postgres. And in this particular case also the setting for `standard_conforming_strings`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The letter **`E`** in front of the text means *C string* and then you must escape twice, one for the *C string* and one for the *regexp*.

Try with and without **`E`**:

```
regexp_split_to_array('123,45,67\,89', '(?<!\\),')
regexp_split_to_array('123,45,67\,89', E'(?<!\\\\),')
```

Here http://rextester.com/VEE84838 a running example (`unnest()` is just for row by row display of results):

```
select unnest(regexp_split_to_array('123,45,67\,89', '(?<!\\),'));
select unnest(regexp_split_to_array('123,45,67\,89', E'(?<!\\\\),'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also split it to groups first:

(\d+),(\d+\,\d+)?

( and later on concatenate them with comma)