# replace single quote with dbouble quote inside clob text

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i am inserting a CLOB data into a table.
as part of this, I am inserting a complete plsql procedure into a clob column. Procedure has many dynamic sql statements. when inserting its throwing ora error.

sample code:

```
insert into t_prc_cmpre( prc_nm,vrsn_nbr,v_CLOB ,envr) 
    (select 'PRC_1','3.7.5',
  'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC1 
IS

v_sql clob;

BEGIN

v_stmt:='INSERT INTO '||v_targetschema||'.'|| PI_TABLE ||' (COL1,COL2,COL3...)

execute immediate v_stmt;
end;
/'
```

since insert statement has single quote ,its not allowing to insert into clob column. 
Please help me to resolve the issue.

Many a thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql) Short answer: Escape each single quote with a second single quotes `'So your string literal looks like ''this'''`Although this practice of storing procedure code in a field is scratching an anti-pattern itch.

Comment: Try douling each single quote within the quoted text.

Comment: There is also the q-quote syntax - see the [documentation for Text Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA).

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to insert 'awkward' data is with the the 'q' syntax, eg

```
insert into t ( c) values ( q'{ This is some text with 'quotes' etc}' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do and your block is incomplete and won't compile. But if you're trying to put a ' character inside a varchar or clob, you enter it as two 's, like this:

```
x := 'The cat''s whiskers';
```