# Syntax error at or near "(" while calling function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.5

While running this code, I am getting following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "(";
>   error while executing the query(7)

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION obs_updated_date() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  i RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN
    (SELECT r FROM pg_class
      WHERE r LIKE 'abc%1')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'update' || i || 'SET observation_time = xyz + INTERVAL"18 hour"';
  END LOOP;
RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT obs_updated_date();
DROP FUNCTION obs_updated_date();
```

Comment: You are missing spaces in the update clause, use: `EXECUTE 'update ' || i || ' SET ...`

Comment: I did that. But still it is showing the same error.

Comment: Yes same error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "(";
error while executing the query(7)

Comment: sorry for that. The error message is edit one. To confirm the error is ERROR: syntax error at or near "("; error while executing the query(7)

Comment: I get a different error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("`
`LINE 1: update(traffic_a_1)SET observation_time = date_added + INTER...`

Comment: Why Postgres 9.1 *and* 9.5?

Comment: `SELECT r FROM pg_class` is an invalid query. `pg_class` has not column named `r`

Answer (score 2):

The main error are double quotes where you need single quotes for the literal value:

```
INTERVAL "18 hour"
```

```
INTERVAL '18 hour'
```

But since that's nested in a quoted string I suggest outer dollar quotes:

```
 EXECUTE 'update' || i || $u$SET observation_time = date_added + INTERVAL '18 hour'$u$;
```

Related:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Better yet, quote the table name properly using `format()`:

```
 EXECUTE format ($u$UPDATE %I SET observation_time = date_added + INTERVAL '18 hour'$u$, i);
```

And you can't use a `record` variable like you did. And some more improvements, resulting in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION obs_updated_date()
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl regclass;
   _ct  int := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN
      SELECT oid
      FROM   pg_class
      WHERE  relname LIKE 'traffic%1'
      AND    relkind = 'r'   -- only actual tables
      AND    relnamespace::regnamespace::text NOT LIKE 'pg_%' -- no system tables
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format ($u$UPDATE %I SET observation_time = date_added + interval '18 hour'$u$, _tbl);
      _ct := _ct + 1;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN _ct;  -- return sth useful: the number of affected tables
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You don't need a `record` to begin with. `text` would do it. Better, yet, use type `regclass` for the table names, since that automatically adds schema names where required. Else, this might go terribly wrong with table names that are used in multiple schemas.

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

**For 1-time use** (as indicated by your dangling `DROP FUNCTION`) consider a [**`DO`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement instead of a function:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _tbl regclass;
   _ct  int := 0;
BEGIN

   ...

   RAISE NOTICE '% tables updated.', _ct;
END
$do$;
```

Comment: You also cannot use a `record` variable like you did.

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors in the code:

- `i` is a `RECORD`, i.e. a whole row of results. Concatenating it to a string implicitly puts `(` `)` around it, producing `update(trafficfoo1)SET ...`. This is what causes the syntax error. You need to either use `i.relname` or declare `i` as `TEXT`.
- There are missing spaces around `i` in the generated string.
- The wrong kind of quotes are used for `"18 hour"`. Double quotes are for identifiers, not strings. `'18 hour'` (single quotes) work, but in the context of a single-quoted string `'` needs to be escaped as `''`, giving `''18 hour''`.

A working version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION obs_updated_date() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  i TEXT;
--  ^^^^
BEGIN
  FOR i IN
    SELECT relname FROM pg_class
      WHERE relname LIKE 'traffic%1'
  LOOP
    execute 'update ' || i || ' SET observation_time = date_added + INTERVAL''18 hour''';
--                 ^           ^                                            ^^       ^^
  END LOOP;
RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```