# How to insert postgresql data with single quotes - Ask it again

Tags: postgresql

**@a_horse_with_no_name - 
Before you close it again !**

I know this post - but it does not solve !
*Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL (7 answers)*

---

I want to insert text with singles quotes into Postgresql 12 database.

```
repmondb=# insert into TEST ("vorname#") values ('\'hans\'');
ungültige Anweisung \'');
Versuchen Sie \? für Hilfe.
```

or

```
repmondb-# insert into TEST ("vorname#") values (''hans'');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "hans"
ZEILE 1: insert into TEST ("vorname#") values ('\'hans
```

The escaping with \ and with extra ' does not work.

Comment: The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/)  **is** the answer for this and the answer to that question also solves your problem. The necessary syntax is clearly [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) in the manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes:

```
insert into TEST ("vorname#") values ('''hans''');
```

Dollar quoted string:

```
insert into TEST ("vorname#") values ($$'hans'$$);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7162f044b6a134ae58f3a2c26be0efd0)**