# How to execute a query with a column name passed as parameter to a plpgsql function?

Tags: postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql

I have a table with multiple columns in PostgreSQL. I try to make a function returning a table with a few default columns and a variable column. The column name should be passed as function parameter. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM get_gas('temperature');
```

This is my code right now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_gas(gas text) 
RETURNS TABLE (id INTEGER, node_id INTEGER, 
                  gas_name DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                  measurement_timestamp timestamp without time zone )
AS 
$$
BEGIN
  SELECT measurements_lora.id, measurements_lora.node_id, gas, measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp
  AS  measure
  FROM public.measurements_lora;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When passing, for example, *'temperature'* as column name (`gas`), I want to get a table with these columns from the function call.

`id - node_id - temperature - measurement_timestamp`

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXECUTE` statement.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_gas(gas text) RETURNS TABLE (f1 INTEGER, f2 INTEGER, f3 DOUBLE PRECISION, f4 timestamp without time zone ) AS
    $$
        DECLARE
           sql_to_execute TEXT;
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'SELECT measurements_lora.id, 
                           measurements_lora.node_id, '
                           || gas ||',
                           measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp AS  measure
                      FROM public.measurements_lora ' 
              INTO sql_to_execute;
            RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql_to_execute;
        END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This will create a variable `sql_to_execute` with your field and. `QUERY EXECUTE` will execute your interpreted query.

**EDIT 1:** Look at the another answer the concernings about security issues.

Comment: I tried this, but got the following error:
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM get_gas('temperature')

Comment: I solved it by changing the return to table:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_gas(gas text) 
    RETURNS TABLE (f1 INTEGER, f2 INTEGER, 
      f3 DOUBLE PRECISION, 
      f4 timestamp without time zone )
   AS $$
       ...

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes - use `SELECT INTO` only when you read from a table. When it is not necessary, then use classic assignment statement `:=`. It is faster and more readable.

Comment: *Never* concatenate user input into SQL statements without defending against SQL injection. This is how you nuke a database.

Comment: I believe that @ErwinBrandstetter is a better (safer) approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need dynamic SQL in a PL/pgSQL function ([which you don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62020050/939860)), be sure to defend against **SQL injection**! Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_gas(gas text)
  RETURNS TABLE (id integer
               , node_id integer 
               , gas_name double precision 
               , measurement_timestamp timestamp)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
   'SELECT m.id, m.node_id, m.%I, m.measurement_timestamp
    FROM   public.measurements_lora m'
  , gas
   );
END
$func$;
```

The format specifier `%I`  in `format()` double-quotes identifiers where needed,

See:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Comment: Look at this detail, to avoid SQL injection if your variable, in some way, is manipulated by a form.