# How do I write a function in plpgsql that compares a date with a timestamp without time zone?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, date, plpgsql

I want to write a function that returns a table with all the rows between `firstDate` and `lastDate`. The rows have datatype *timestamp without time zone* They also have to be of a specific node id.

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_measurements_by_node_and_date(nodeID INTEGER, firstDate date, lastDate date) 
RETURNS TABLE (measurement_id INTEGER, node_id INTEGER, carbon_dioxide DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                    hydrocarbons DOUBLE PRECISION, temperature DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                    humidity DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                    air_pressure DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                    measurement_timestamp timestamp without time zone ) AS
$$
    DECLARE
       sql_to_execute TEXT;
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'SELECT measurements_lora.id, 
                       measurements_lora.node_id,
                       measurements_lora.carbon_dioxide,
                       measurements_lora.hydrocarbons,
                       measurements_lora.temperature,
                       measurements_lora.humidity,
                       measurements_lora.air_pressure,
                       measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp AS  measure
                  FROM public.measurements_lora 
                  WHERE  measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp <= '||lastDate||'
                  AND    measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp >= '||firstDate||'           
                  AND    measurements_lora.node_id = '||nodeID||' ' 
          INTO sql_to_execute;
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql_to_execute;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The column measurement_timestamp is of type timestamp without time zone and is formatted like yy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss

When I run `SELECT * FROM get_measurements_by_node_and_date(1, '2020-5-1', '2020-5-24')`

I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone <= integer
> LINE 10: ...   WHERE  measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp <= 2020-05...
> ```

I don't get why it says "integer", because I clearly defined `firstDate` and `lastDate` as type `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What Pavel said.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62007007/939860)

What's more, nothing indicates a need for PL/pgSQL to begin with. A plain (prepared) `SELECT` statement can do it. Or an SQL function, if you want to persist it in the database. See:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

And concerning:

> with all the rows between `firstDate` and `lastDate`

Define inclusive / exclusive upper / lower bound *precisely* to avoid surprising corner case results. When comparing a `timestamp` column to a `date`, the latter is coerced to the timestamp signifying the first instance of the day: `YYYY.MM.DD 00:00:00`.

Your query says:

```
measurement_timestamp <= lastDate AND measurement_timestamp >= firstDate
```

... which would include all of `firstDate`, but ***exclude all of `lastDate` except for the first (common) instance at 00:00***. Typically not what you want. Given your formulation, I suppose this is what you really want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_measurements_by_node_and_date(node_id integer
                                                           , firstDate date
                                                           , lastDate date) 
  RETURNS TABLE (measurement_id integer
               , node_id integer
               , carbon_dioxide float8
               , hydrocarbons float8
               , temperature float8
               , humidity float8
               , air_pressure float8
               , measurement_timestamp timestamp)
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
   SELECT m.id
        , m.node_id
        , m.carbon_dioxide
        , m.hydrocarbons
        , m.temperature
        , m.humidity
        , m.air_pressure
        , m.measurement_timestamp -- AS measure  -- just documentation
   FROM   public.measurements_lora m
   WHERE  m.node_id = _node_id
   AND    m.measurement_timestamp >= firstDate::timestamp
   AND    m.measurement_timestamp < (lastDate + 1)::timestamp  -- ①!
$func$;
```

① This includes all of `lastDate`, and efficiently. You can just [add / subtract an `integer` value to / from a `date` to add / subtract days](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE). The explicit cast to `::timestamp` is optional as date would be coerced in the expression automatically. But since we are trying to clear up confusion here ...

Related:

- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281)

Aside 1:

> The column `measurement_timestamp` is of type `timestamp without time zone` and is formatted like *yy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss*

No. `timestamp` values are *not* formatted, period. They are just timestamp values (internally stored as the number of microseconds since the epoch). Display is completely separate from the value and can be adjusted in a hundred and one ways without changing the *value*. Get rid of this misconception to better understand what's going on. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Aside 2:

About the devious nature of SQL `BETWEEN`:

- [How to add a day/night indicator to a timestamp column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/267877/3684)

Aside 3:

Consider legal, lower-case identifiers in Postgres. `first_date` instead of `firstDate`. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Related:

- [PostgreSQL function returning a data cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240052/postgresql-function-returning-a-data-cube/55241505#55241505)
- [Postgresql trying to use execute format in a function but getting column not found error when giving string format in coalesce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531881/postgresql-trying-to-use-execute-format-in-a-function-but-getting-column-not-fou/61532400#61532400)

Answer (score 2):

In this case is good to write executed query first. I try to reduce your example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(d date)
 RETURNS TABLE(o integer)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare q text;
begin
  q := 'select 1 from generate_series(1,100) where current_timestamp <= ' || d ;
  raise notice '%', q;
  return query execute q;
end;
$function$

postgres=# select * from foo('2020-05-25');
NOTICE:  00000: select 1 from generate_series(1,100) where current_timestamp <= 2020-05-25
LOCATION:  exec_stmt_raise, pl_exec.c:3826
ERROR:  42883: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone <= integer
LINE 1: ...om generate_series(1,100) where current_timestamp <= 2020-05...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  select 1 from generate_series(1,100) where current_timestamp <= 2020-05-25
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function foo(date) line 6 at RETURN QUERY
```

I got same error message. So there are more than one error:

1. The dynamic query is not valid - the where clause looks like

   `where current_timestamp <= 2020-05-25`

   and you can see, it is not valid - there are not quotes. You can fix it, when you use quotes manually (but it is strong error and don't do it, or you can use function `quote_literal` like `where current_timestamp <= ' || quote_literal(d)`.

   Now produced query is correct:

   ```
   select 1 from generate_series(1,100) where current_timestamp <= '2020-05-25'
   ```
2. But in this case, is much better to use `EXECUTE USING`. When a variable is used as query parameter (not as table or column name), then you can use `USING` clause. Then you don't need to use quoting:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(d date)
    RETURNS TABLE(o integer)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS $function$
   declare q text;
   begin
     q := 'select 1 from generate_series(1,100) where current_timestamp <= $1';
     return query execute q using d;
   end;
   $function$
   ```
3. but the big mistake is using dynamic SQL when it is not necessary (like your example). There is not any visible reason why you use `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` statement. You can use just `RETURN QUERY`:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_measurements_by_node_and_date(nodeID INTEGER, firstDate date, lastDate date) 
   RETURNS TABLE (measurement_id INTEGER, node_id INTEGER, carbon_dioxide DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                  hydrocarbons DOUBLE PRECISION, temperature DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                  humidity DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                  air_pressure DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                  measurement_timestamp timestamp without time zone ) AS
   $$
   BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY SELECT measurements_lora.id, 
                          measurements_lora.node_id,
                          measurements_lora.carbon_dioxide,
                          measurements_lora.hydrocarbons,
                          measurements_lora.temperature,
                          measurements_lora.humidity,
                          measurements_lora.air_pressure,
                          measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp AS  measure
                     FROM public.measurements_lora 
                     WHERE measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp <= lastDate 
                       AND measurements_lora.measurement_timestamp >= firstDate           
                       AND measurements_lora.node_id = nodeID;
   END
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```