# Best data structure to store long strings of digits

Tags: types, numbers, amazon-redshift, sqldatatypes

I have a column of numbers (maximum length of each number is 14 digits) and each character in each number is exclusively digit (so no letters or special characters inside the numbers).

I've tried assigning the data type `int4` and `int8` to the numbers column, and load the table into Redshift (PostgreSQL). However, I kept getting the error below:

```
numeric value "9555739320" out of range for integer
```

This confused me because I thought int8 is `bigint` type which can store very huge numbers, as stated in session **8.1. Numeric Types** in this site: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html. If my understanding is correct, why would the number "9555739320" be out of range?

Is there any recommendation on what data type to assign this number column to? Let's say that some numbers might have leading 0s, for example "000223568960", and I want to preserve every digit including the 0s.

Comment: "*I thought `int4` is `bigint` type*" - that's not what the page you linked says.

Comment: Aside: Redshift is *not* Postgres. It has been forked a very long time and differences have been growing ever since. The Postgres manual for version 8.1 is as close as it gets, but still far from it. Stick to the (inferior, granted) documentation of Amazon for their product: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/welcome.html

Comment: @Bergi: In this particular case it makes kind of sense that the OP pointed to the 8.1 manual instead of the current one. (All the same for the actual problem, though.)

Comment: @Bergi thanks for catching that. I made a typo meant to say "int8" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your error message unmistakably states:

> numeric value "9555739320" out of range for integer

"integer". If you had actually tried to assign to a `int8` column, the error message would say "bigint", not "integer". Except that it wouldn't, as 9555739320 is easily in the bigint range of -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 - like you stated yourself.

`int8` is an alias for `bigint`.
`int4` or just `int` are aliases for `integer`.

> Let's say that some numbers might have leading 0s, for example "000223568960", and I want to preserve every digit including the 0s.

If you want to preserve a variable number of leading zeros, you cannot use any of the [numeric data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html), which trim such insignificant noise. Use `text` or `varchar` instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Erwin Brandsetter. It's interesting I've tried assign the column "text" type, but still won't work. This time the error says "numeric value "37167582983" out of range for integer". I am confused because I assigned it "text" type why it would still treat it as an "integer".

Comment: @Stan: It wouldn't. There must be another, unnecessary cast to integer in the food chain. Find it and eliminate it. Be sure that your (now) string constants are properly single-quoted. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860