# Postgres: strings in column during update ERROR: syntax error at or near

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I am trying to update a value in my Postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE restaurants 
(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    price_range INT NOT NULL CHECK (price_range >= 1 AND price_range <=5)
);
```

Here is the update that wouldn't work:

```
UPDATE restaurants 
SET location = ”los angeles”,
    name = ‘tacos los guichos’,
    price_range = 2
WHERE id = 27;
```

The terminal says:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "angeles”"
> LINE 3: location=”los angeles”,
> ^

My table does not seem to like strings when updating, even though I am able to insert them. So I am not sure why? When I removed the name and location column, it updated fine.

Comment: Don't use fancy single or double quotes for string literals. Don't user normal double quotes either, they're for identifiers. Just normal 7 bit ASCII single quotes: `'`. So `location = 'los angeles'` and `name = 'tacos los guichos'`... Hint: Always write your code in a plain text editor, **never** use any rich text editor or any office text program like Microsoft Word or LibreOffice Writer to do so.

Comment: Makes so much sense! That is definitely key knowledge. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres (as in standard SQL):
`'Strings'` are quoted with single quotes.
`"Identifiers"` can be quoted with double quotes.

Typographic quotes like in `”los angeles”` or `‘tacos los guichos’` don't do anything useful.

See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very useful to know