# format SQL date string

Tags: postgresql, date, format

I'm trying to get a date formatted between quotes on a select format() query:

```
select format('CREATE TABLE temporary_table AS
          SELECT id FROM table WHERE created >=%I ORDER BY 1 ASC LIMIT 1','2021-04-01');
```

I'm getting this:

```
CREATE TABLE temporary_table AS
              SELECT table FROM table WHERE created >="2021-04-01" ORDER BY 1 ASC LIMIT 1;
```

And I wanted to actually get the date between single quotes (as this won't work on an execute)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single-quoted *values* you need the specifier **`%L`** for [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT). Like:

```
SELECT format('CREATE TABLE temporary_table AS
      SELECT id FROM table WHERE created >= %L ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1','2021-04-01');
```

See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Of course that only makes sense if you parameterize the input. You wouldn't bother to use `format()` for a constant date to begin with.