# Postgresql - Escape single qoutes in dynamic queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

> Version: PG-13.3 with pgAdmin4

How do I escape single quotes in dynamic SQL in a function?

Here is my code

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    uuid text;
BEGIN
        uuid := 'X-2132135671';
        -- Create a function using above id
        EXECUTE format(E'CREATE FUNCTION system_uid() RETURNS text AS \'SELECT %L\' LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;', uuid);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

here when I try to execute the code I am getting error as below

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "X"
LINE 1: ...UNCTION system_uid() RETURNS text AS 'SELECT 'X-21321356...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  CREATE FUNCTION system_uid() RETURNS text AS 'SELECT 'X-2132135671'' LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

Please suggest correct way of doing this.

Comment: Basics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple ["dollar quotes"](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/dollar-quoted-string-constants/):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    uuid text;
BEGIN
  uuid := 'X-2132135671';
  -- Create a function using above id
  EXECUTE format($f$CREATE FUNCTION system_uid() RETURNS text AS $s$SELECT %L$s$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;$f$, uuid);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=df9f8aba25404c1b4c7debcc78ab43ef)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to nested "dollar quotes" I recommend building the SQL statement you want prior to the Execute statement itself and doing a "raise notice/log"on that statement. Doing so gives you the advantage of seeing the actual statement you actually run. That way when a error occurs you can see the exact statement you ran. Something like:

```
do $do$
declare
    k_base constant text :=
           $stmt$
               create function system_uid() 
                 returns text 
                 language sql immutable                      
               as $$ select %L; $$;
           $stmt$;
     
    l_uuid text;
    l_stmt text; 

begin
        l_uuid := 'X-2132135671';
        -- create a function using above id
        l_stmt = format (k_base, l_uuid);
        raise notice e'Running Statement:\n%',l_stmt; 
        execute l_stmt;  
end;
$do$;
```

Caution: UUID is a defined data type in Postgres so you should avoid using it a a column/variable name. It has a predefined structure (32hex digits). Be careful that you do not cause confusion.