# Python find a string with single quote symbol in postgresql table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to look up for a string that contains multiple single quotes from my psql table. My current solution is replacing the single quotes with double single quotes like this:

```
sql_query = f"""SELECT exists (SELECT 1 FROM {table_name} WHERE my_column = '{my_string.replace("'","''")}' LIMIT 1);"""
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

Is there a nicer solution for this kind of formatting ?

Comment: I also tried $$my_string$$ but this disturbs the cases where I have a dollar sign in my string

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-matching.html#:~:text=9.7.3.%20posix%20regular%20expressions

Comment: I think you need a [Postgres escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making the query like this

```
sql_query = f"""SELECT exists (SELECT 1 FROM {table_name} WHERE my_column = %s LIMIT 1);"""
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query, (mystring,))
```

In this case it formats `mystring` in such way that it is not executed as sql query and doesn't cause the problems mentioned in the question