# How to update a text field with broken JSON literals in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have a lot of character varying records in this format: `{'address': 'New Mexico'}`.
I would like to update all those columns to have it like this: `New Mexico`.

I've been investigating how to do it, and it could be with regexp, but I don't know how to make for all columns in a table, and I never used regex in PostgreSQL before.

I have an idea that is something like this:

```
SET location = regexp_replace(field, 'match pattern', 'replace string', 'g')
```

Comment: Postgres has built in tools for manipulating json. Have you tried something like `location::json->>'address'` ?

Comment: I'm trying this: UPDATE web_scraping.iws_informacion_web_scraping
SET iws_localizacion = iws_localizacion::json -> 'address'
WHERE iws_id = 3678; But I'm getting this: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "'" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {'...
SQL state: 22P02

Comment: This is the reason the column should have been defined as `jsonb` (or `json`) from the start. Then you wouldn't need to fix the data now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid JSON literals require double-quotes where your sample displays single quotes. Maybe you can fix that upstream?

To repair (assuming there are no other, unrelated single-quotes involved):

```sql
UPDATE web_scraping.iws_informacion_web_scraping
SET    iws_localizacion = replace(iws_localizacion, '''', '"')::json ->> 'address'
WHERE  iws_id = 3678
AND    iws_localizacion IS DISTINCT FROM replace(iws_localizacion, '''', '"')::json ->> 'address';
```

The 2nd `WHERE` clause prevents updates to rows that wouldn't change. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Optional if such cases can be excluded.

Comment: Great! It works smoothly, just a question, why in the replace clause you use four single quotation marks instead of three,  I understand we want to change ' for '', but when I remove it I get an error, I suppose it's because postgresql detect it like a quotation mark without its respective closing quotation mark.

Comment: @marshelv: About single quotes in quoted strings, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860