# How to use $$ as string value inside pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Im building parameterised sql using pgp and wrapping the generated sql inside DO $$ END $$. Problem is when I try saving password (varchar) some of the password hashes contain $$ which causes issues since the psql is inside DO $$ END $$. My question, Is it possible to somehow escape $$ or save password hash with $$ inside it but without plpgsql erroring out.

sample generated plpgsql

```
DO $$ DECLARE parent_user int; 
BEGIN  CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_f6a8e872_b346_4184_889d_52ffeded463f (id int); 
INSERT INTO form_user(firstname,lastname,displayname,job_title,username,authentication_type,password,password2,password_reset,role,comm_portal,issue_ticket,email,rec_sms,created_by,created_on,auto_name) 
VALUES ('delete','delete','delete','admin','delete','password','$p5k2$$9kenbgnr$XuoSekYV4qQlDE0NkNEs2UGJEEIWtjG/','$p5k2$$7cxgxz4n$JSkgV8oGg72S1O6i2xYZSLEU2Yd6bdCO','0','admin','No','No','delete@delete.com','No',22,'11/5/2023 19:59:45','delete delete (admin)') RETURNING id INTO parent_user; 
INSERT INTO tmp_f6a8e872_b346_4184_889d_52ffeded463f (id) VALUES (parent_user);
END; $$;
```

Error
error: syntax error at or near "9"

Comment: Why are you using plpgsql at all for this?

Comment: That is *not* a parameterised statement.

Comment: Tag the `$$`: `select $tag$$p5k2$$9kenbgnr$XuoSekYV4qQlDE0NkNEs2UGJEEIWtjG/$tag$; $p5k2$$9kenbgnr$XuoSekYV4qQlDE0NkNEs2UGJEEIWtjG/`. Per [Syntax Lexical](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html): *4.1.2.4. Dollar-Quoted String Constants*

Comment: [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is the Postgres interactive terminal. [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) is the procedural language, [pgp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) is an encryption program. You are mixing terms freely. More accuracy will also help to clear up confusion with quoted strings.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry for the confusion I am using pg-promise and NOT pgp purely my bad.

Comment: @Bergi I am using pg-promise to do the parameterisation and I thought pasting this instead of parameters would be more helpful, and using the plpgsql to do transactional INSERTS and UPDATES across multiple tables in a single go.

Comment: I would recommend to simply control the transaction with pg-promise, or use a CTE if you want to do in a single go.

Comment: @Bergi the pg-promise transaction takes too much time, so for my actual query where I have roughly around 11ish tables that I have to UPSERT in a single transaction the transaction time alone takes about 10 times more then this way, I have not explored CTE though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While dealing with a single **known** string constant, just add a token to your dollar-quotes that is not repeated in the string:

```sql
DO
$do$  -- $do$ instead of just $$
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tbl AS 
   WITH ins1 AS (
      INSERT INTO form_user(firstname,lastname,displayname,job_title,username,authentication_type,password,password2,password_reset,role,comm_portal,issue_ticket,email,rec_sms,created_by,created_on,auto_name) 
      VALUES ('delete','delete','delete','admin','delete','password','$p5k2$$9kenbgnr$XuoSekYV4qQlDE0NkNEs2UGJEEIWtjG/','$p5k2$$7cxgxz4n$JSkgV8oGg72S1O6i2xYZSLEU2Yd6bdCO','0','admin','No','No','delete@delete.com','No',22,'11/5/2023 19:59:45','delete delete (admin)')
      RETURNING id
      )
   TABLE ins;
END
$do$;
```

Also, you don't need the intermediate step with a variable. I would just use the SQL without the wrapping `DO` command, which doesn't add anything useful in the example.

When dealing with **unknown** string input, and you need a quoted string literal (like for dynamic SQL, unlike the given example!) use the function `quote_literal()` or the equivalent `format('%s', $input)` to build a string with a nested string literal. Each produces a valid string literal automatically, escaping all special characters as needed. (There must be an input *variable* or *parameter* in such a case for initial input.

See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Comment: that worked, this is a focused part of a bigger query which needs the variable to store the id in psql var which is later, within the same script, used to save in subsequent tables.

Comment: I see. plpgsql var, not psql.

Comment: Yes, thank you for correction

Answer (score 0):

The `$$` is a special type of string called [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING). The `$$` indicates the start and end of a string just like `'` does.

```
select 'this is a string' || $$ and so is this$$
```

You can put more characters between the `$$` to make a unique delimiter like `$body$`. This is called a "tag".

```
select $body$this is a string$body$
```

Comment: But nothing guarantees that the password wouldn't contain `$body$` either

Comment: @Bergi The contents of the string are known, so you pick the appropriate delimiter for the string.