# How to remove the quotes from a string for SQL query in Python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a dictionary of database names.  I take a name from the dictionary

```
database_name = database_dict[i]
```

lets say the value for database_name is 'foo'

Using Psycopg2 I am executing a statement:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES(...);", database_name)
```

I get A syntax error at foo, because it should be "INSERT INTO foo VALUES" not "INSERT INTO 'foo' VALUES"

Any advice how to pass in a string value for the name of the table and removing the single quotes?  Should I place an escape character inside my database dictionary values?

EDIT: Something closer is here: [How do I remove single quotes from a table in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587162/how-do-i-remove-single-quotes-from-a-table-in-postgresql)

but I could not get it to work using REMOVE.  It gave a syntax error at the single quote inside the remove statement.

Comment: Identifiers (such as table and column names) use double quotes in standard SQL (and PostgreSQL) so you need to use an identifier-specific quoting method. AFAIK this means [`quote_ident`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.quote_ident) and string concatenation but I don't know enough Python  or Psycopg2 to be sure of the best/right way.

Comment: Is the value in `database_dict[i]` `'foo'` or `foo`? Where are the quotes coming from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The structural components of an SQL query such as table and field names cannot be parameterized as you attempt in second argument of `cursor.execute(query, params)`. Only numeric/literal data values can be parameterized.

Consider interpolating the *database_name* variable into the SQL query string but do so safely with psycopg2's [`sqlIdentifier()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) with `str.format`:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
...

cur.execute(sql.SQL('INSERT INTO {} VALUES(...)').format(sql.Identifier(database_name)))
```

---

Valid [parameterizaiton](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) in your case would be to bind the data values passed in the `VALUES(...)` in append query such as `VALUES(%s, %s, %s)`. Alternatively in other queries:

```
"SELECT %s AS NewColumn..."

"...WHERE fieldname = %s OR otherfield IN (%s, %s, %s)"

"...HAVING Max(NumColumn) >= %s"
```

Comment: Direct interpolation without escaping the `database_name` invites a SQL injection attack.

Comment: By using .format, I was able to overcome this limitation.  Thank you @Parfait

Comment: There is no risk of SQL injection because there are no fields to fill out in my application.

Comment: @SteveScott The unquoted, unescaped `database_name` itself is the risk. It should be run through `quote_ident` if you're going to build a SQL query with string methods like `.format`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks to @Schwern pyscopg2 has the [`sql.Identifier()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) method to separate the string and variable parts of query for safe interpolation for identifiers. See edit.

Comment: @Parfait Great find! It's so weird they don't just have a `%i` and I'm not aware of any database interface that does.

Comment: Python in general does use, `%`, for string interpolation where `str.format` is preferred but as docs show not safe for queries. Of course the safest for OP will be to code a stored function directly in postgres and call it at application layer.

Answer (score 22):

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES(...);", AsIs(database_name))
```

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs

BTW that is not a database name, it is a table name.

Comment: I believe `AsIs(quote_ident(database_name))` would be the complete answer to avoid the possibility of a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Using AsIs() is the correct answer, and should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I haven't use psycopg2, this is based on what I know from similar database libraries.*

A table name is an identifier and they get quoted and escaped differently than values. I believe you should use [`psycopg2.extensions.quote_ident(str, scope)`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.ISQLQuote) to quote and escape it. I believe it uses the PostgreSQL function [`PQescapeIdentifier()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQESCAPEIDENTIFIER).

> PQescapeIdentifier escapes a string for use as an SQL identifier, such as a table, column, or function name. This is useful when a user-supplied identifier might contain special characters that would otherwise not be interpreted as part of the identifier by the SQL parser, or when the identifier might contain upper case characters whose case should be preserved.

Then it will be quoted and escaped and can be safely added to the SQL string using normal string operations without risking a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), or using `AsIs(quote_ident(database_name))` as a value to `.execute`.

Answer (score -2):

If fact, `database_name` is `"'foo'"`.

To drop the single quote:

```
database_name = database_name.replace("'", "")
```

Comment: That is not correct.  My value is a string.  I cannot insert a string into the SQL statement without the single quotes.  Your suggestion did not work.

Comment: Right, %s wraps it in single quotes, but I cannot have quotes in the SQL statement.