# Passing a datetime into psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a datetime value into my postgres database using Psycopg2.

My code was working before, but I switched from %s notation to {} notation, and my code broke.

here is my code

```
for j in eveLists.itemList:
    tempPrice = fetchSellPrice(i, j)
    database_name = eveLists.DatabaseDict[i]
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES ({1}, {2}, {3}, NULL, {4}, {5}, NULL);".format(
                                                                                       database_name,
                                                                                       str(i),
                                                                                       str(j),
                                                                                       float(tempPrice),
                                                                                       datetime.date.today(),
                                                                                       now))
```

I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "00"
LINE 1: ...0000142, 2268, 3.11, NULL, 2017-05-09, 2017-05-10 00:40:03.3...
                                                             ^
```

It is treating the date and the time as two separate objects.

I have tried several different ways which are commented out, and all throw various error messages. I have tried wrapping the datetime in quotes,

```
now = ("'%s'") % str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

which give an error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "mydate" is of type date but expression is of type integer
LINE 1: ...NTO temp_jita VALUES (30000142, 2268, 3.11, NULL, 2017-05-09...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

It thinks my date is an integer, even though I wrapped it in quotes.

I have also tried making a psycopg2 timestamp manually:

```
now = psycopg2.Timestamp(now.strftime("%Y"),
                                     now.strftime("%m"),
                                     now.strftime("%d"),
                                     now.strftime("%h"),
                                     now.strftime("%M"),
                                     int(now.strftime("%-S")))
```

Which gives the following error:

```
    int(now.strftime("%-S")))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I don't know how it thinks this is a string, especially since I cast it as an int!

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The reason I passed the variables using {} notation and not %s notation is because I received an error for the following code:

```
  for j in eveLists.itemList:
            tempPrice = fetchSellPrice(i, j)
            database_name = eveLists.DatabaseDict[i]
            now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            now = str(now)

            cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s, %s, %s, NULL, %s, %s, NULL);", [database_name,
                                                                                    str(i),
                                                                                    str(j),
                                                                                    float(tempPrice),
                                                                                    datetime.date.today(),
                                                                                    now
                                                                                    ])

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'temp_jita'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO 'temp_jita' VALUES ('30000142', '2268', 3.03, NU...
                    ^
```

Please refer to my previous post on the subject: [How to remove the quotes from a string for SQL query in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877210/how-to-remove-the-quotes-from-a-string-for-sql-query-in-python)

EDIT: following @Zorg 's advice from this link (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html), this code worked for me:

```
cur.execute(sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s, %s, %s, NULL, %s, %s, NULL);").format(sql.Identifier(database_name)),[
                                                                                    str(i),
                                                                                    str(j),
                                                                                    float(tempPrice),
                                                                                    datetime.date.today(),
                                                                                    now
                                                                                    ])
```

Comment: What types are this columns in the DB?  And this post is confusing because in one case the error is for field 4, and in another it is for field 5?

Comment: and if you just wrap dates to `str(now)`?..

Comment: if you wrap it like str(now) you get the first error at the hour.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you read ["Psycopg2 usage"](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html)?

If not, don't hesitate to do so.

> Warning NEVER, NEVER, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Proper way of passing params into a query is shown below:

```
 SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES (%s);" # Note: no quotes
 data = ("O'Reilly", )
 cur.execute(SQL, data) # Note: no % operator
```

Comment: I tried using %s, but if you pass a variable into the  (name) field it adds quotation marks, which breaks the SQL code.  That is why I used {} notation.

Comment: Thanks Zorg.  This looks like the right article for me.

Comment: For whom is to lazy to read the docs: SQL-Injection (attacks) are the main reason to only use the framework's query-string handling (ie. unquoted `%s`)

Answer (score 8):

[AsIs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs) and[`quote_ident`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.quote_ident)

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs, quote_ident

cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO %s
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, NULL, %s, %s, NULL);
""", (
    AsIs(quote_ident(database_name, cur)),
    str(i),
    str(j),
    float(tempPrice),
    datetime.date.today(),
    now
))
```