# Not able to pass datetime object into postgresql using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, psycopg2

I need to pass some insert data into postgres which also contains a timestamp. I am using psycopg2 for the same.

I have tried to follow the answer here upon getting the same error as the one asked in the question: [Passing a datetime into psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881999/passing-a-datetime-into-psycopg2)

My code which doesn't work:

```
recv_data = {"datetime":datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 5, 12, 56, 34, 617607)
             "temperature": 40, "humidity":80}

insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO temp_humidity (temperature,humidity,datetime) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
data = (recv_data["temperature"], recv_data["humidity"], recv_data["datetime"])
print(insert_stmt)
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
connection.commit()
```

ERROR:

> ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
>
> STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO temp_humidity (temperature,humidity,datetime) VALUES (42,79,'2019-12-05T05:55:45.135111'::timestamp)

Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp seems to be OK,

```sql
SELECT '2019-12-05T05:55:45.135111'::timestamp;
         timestamp          
----------------------------
 2019-12-05 05:55:45.135111
(1 row)
```

The problem seems to be elsewhere, maybe in a constraint check?
Can you obtain the precise error message from `psycopg2` exception or `PostgreSQL` logs?

Comment: Apparently you have Auto commit/rollback from whatever IDE (or command line) you are using turned off. Postgres is waiting for commit or rollback.