# removing quotes when interpolating query value in psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Connected to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877210/how-to-remove-the-quotes-from-a-string-for-sql-query-in-python), but I'm missing something.

When I run the following

```
table_name = 'my_schema.my_table'
cur.execute(sql.SQL('SELECT col1, col2 FROM {}').format(sql.Identifier(table_name)))
```

The query that is sent to the database is

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM "myschema.myname"
```

And I get the error:

```
"relation "myschema.myname" does not exist"
```

I want the query to be

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM myschema.myname
```

When I pass this directly to `cur.execute` I don't have a problem.

---

If it is of help I connect to the database following [this tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/) using a .ini file which in my case looks like:

```
[postgresql]
host=ip_no_of_host
database=name_of_db
user=username
password=password
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't connect to a specific schema just the database, also `myschema.mytable` works fine if I pass it directly to `cur.execute`.

Comment: I've updated my question with conn details. removing the schema qualifier doesn't work - I still have the quotes around the table name.   I don't think this is the issue, because the problem is removing the quote marks. As I said `cur.execute('SELECT col1, col2 FROM myschema.myname')` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
schema_name = 'my_schema'
table_name = 'my_table'
cur.execute(sql.SQL('SELECT col1, col2 FROM {}.{}').format(
    sql.Identifier(schema_name), sql.Identifier(table_name)
    )
)
```

or just

```
table_name = 'my_table'
cur.execute(sql.SQL('SELECT col1, col2 FROM my_schema.{}').format(
    sql.Identifier(table_name)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. Is this because `sql.Identifier(_str_)` objects map onto atomic postgres objects?